# Access Object property using key name within map

Tags: object, ecmascript-6

I have below array of object

```
const reports = [{id:3, name:'three', description:'three d', other: 'other 3'}, {id:2, name:'two', description:'two d', other: 'other 2'}];
```

and I want to filter out only 2 property of each object and below is my desired output

```
[{id:3, name:'three'}, {id:2, name:'two'}];
```

so tried this way

```
const reportList = reports.map((report) => {id,name} );
console.log(reportList);
```

throw error

> ReferenceError: id is not defined

even I can achieve this by using this approach

```
 this.reportList = reports.map((report) => ({
                id: report.id,
                name: report.name,
                description: report.description
            }));
```

but here I need to write extra code, I want to use object accessor using key, can I achieve anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap the returning object literal into parentheses. Otherwise curly braces will be considered to denote the function’s body. The following works:

```js
const reports = [{
  id: 3,
  name: 'three',
  description: 'three d',
  other: 'other 3'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'two',
  description: 'two d',
  other: 'other 2'
}];

const reportList = reports.map(({id, name}) => ({
  id,
  name
}));
console.log(reportList);
```

Reference: [Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) by MDN

Comment: Thanks. got it now.